# Is there a word for the front view of a car from the driver's perspective?

Tags: word-request

Is there a word for the front view of a car from the driver's perspective? i am not sure if there's a word, but the only word or phrase I can think of is "through the windshield" or "front", but using these words sound very awkward.

For example:

> The driver looked through the windshield and saw a giant monster 5km
>   from his current position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the other answer says, there is nothing incorrect or awkward about "through the windshield." However, if you are looking for alternative ways to describe that situation you could go with things like...

The driver looked ahead...
The driver looked forward...
The driver looked up the road...
The driver looked up at the windshield, and saw...
The driver saw a giant monster 5km up the road.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with the use of the phrase "through the windshield".

You can say "the driver looked out the windshield/looked through the windshield".